# Union type between Any? and Unit

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to write a higher order function that will allow me to do this:

```
blah1 { em ->
    // do some stuff here
}
```

as well as this:

```
blah2 { em ->
    // do some stuff here
    listOf("1","2","3")
}
```

In the first example, i'm returning nothing and in the second example I'm return a list of strings.

This works for the first one:

```
inline fun blah1(f: (em: EM) -> Unit): Result {
    f(em)
    return Result()
}
```

For the second one, I need a different return type:

```
inline fun blah2(f: (em: EM) -> Any?): Result {
    val res = f(em)
    when (res) {
        is List<*> -> res.forEach { item ->
            // do something with item
        }
    }
    return Result()
}
```

Is it possible to combine `blah1` and `blah2` so that if I do this:

```
blah { em ->

}
```

`val res = f(em)` res will be of type Unit and when I do this:

```
blah { em ->
   listOf("1","2","3")
}
```

`val res = f(em)` res will be of type List ?

I've tried doing this:

```
inline fun blah(
    noinline f1: (em: EM) -> Unit = f1fun,
    noinline f2: (em: EM) -> Any? = f2fun
): Result {
    f1(em)
    f2(em)?.let { res ->
        when (res) {
            is List<*> -> res.forEach { item ->
                // do something with item
            }
        }
    }
    return Result()
}

val f1fun: (em: EntityManager) -> Unit = { Unit }
val f2fun: (em: EntityManager) -> Any? = { null }
```

... but now whether I do

```
blah { em ->
    // code here    
}
```

or

```
blah { em ->
    // code here
    listOf("1", "2")
}
```

`f2`'s lambda is always executed.

Is there a way to achieve having a `blah { with or without statement }` that will allow you to collect that value as `Any?` if a statement is indeed inside the lambda and when no statement is present, treat it like a `Unit` lambda?

This:
`inline fun blah2(f: (em: EM) -> Any?): Result {`

doesn't compile under certain circumstances:

```
blah2 {
   k = k + 1
}
```

even though this works fine:

```
blah2 {

}
```

and this works fine:

```
blah2 {
  k++
}
```

**Update**: Have logged a bug in the meantime: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20215

Answer (score 3):

This should work for Kotlin:

```
inline fun blah2(f: (em: EM) -> Any?): Result {
    val res = f(EM())
    when (res) {
        is List<*> -> res.forEach { 
            // do something with item
            println("Item: " + it)               
        }
        is Unit -> {
            // do something else
        }
    }
    return Result()
}

fun tryit() {
    var res = blah2 {  }
    res = blah2 { arrayListOf<String>("A","b","c") }
}
```

But if you are trying to call your Kotlin `blah2` from Java code, you may have problems.  This link ([Unit closures required to return Kotlin.Unit](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/java-interop-unit-closures-required-to-return-kotlin-unit/1842)) describes a problem passing a function returning void from Java to a Kotlin method.  I have not followed to see if it's solved.

**Edit**
These should also work:

```
    var k: Int = 0
    res = blah2 { k++ }
    //res = blah2 { k = k + 1 }  // does not compile
    //res = blah2 { k = k + 1; return@blah2 } // does not compile
    res = blah2 { k = k + 1; return@blah2 k }
```

But the two commented lines do not work.  The OP has written a bug report on this (and I agree that it's a bug).  But, keep in mind that if it did work, the behavior would be different than what would be expected from Java.  In Java, `k = k + 1` is an expression, but in Kotlin it is not.  Therefore, the return type of this expression is not `Int`.  If it worked, the return type would be `Nothing` (see [Return and Jumps](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#returns-and-jumps)).  If SO were to port from Java to Kotlin, they need to watch out for "assignments as expressions".  [Here is an interesting discussion on this matter.](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/assignment-not-allow-in-while-expression/339)

**Update**
Here is further example of the inconsistency:

```
class TestLambdaReturnType {
    var k = 1;
    var a: () -> Any = {} //explicitly typed (accepts: () -> Unit )
    val b = { k=2 }       //compiler implicitly types b: () -> Unit
    val c = {}            //compiler implicitly types c: () -> Unit
    val d: () -> Any = {k=2}  //compiler error (??: lambda returns Unit, Unit is derived from Any)
    val e: () -> Unit = { k=2 } //no compiler error
    val f: () -> Any = e // no compiler error: ?? inconsistent

    fun blah2(v: () -> Any): Any = v()

    companion object{
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            val tn = TestLambdaReturnType()
            tn.a = tn.b

            tn.blah2(tn.a) //ni compiler error, no surprise
            tn.blah2(tn.b) //no compiler error, no surprise
            tn.blah2(tn.c) //no compiler error, no surprise
            tn.blah2 { tn.k=2 }  //error: why "f" different than "v"?
        }
    }
}
```

The lambda must have a return type.  In these examples, the return type is Unit.  But based upon these examples, there appears to be two types of `Unit`, one that derives from `Any` and one that derives from `who-knows-what`.

Comment: Yeah, that should work, but it doesn't in all cases, I've logged a bug for it now: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20215

Answer (score 3):

`k = k + 1` is an assignment which is a statement not an expression in Kotlin and it therefore does not evaluate to Unit or any other type.

---

> Why are assignments with no type at all taken into account when the
>   compiler is looking for expressions?

Consider the following short program:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val result = num { a ->
        var b = a * 5
        // ...put whatever code you want here
        // ...and here
        b++ // <- the last line matters
    }
}

fun num(f: (i: Int) -> Int): Int {
    return f(5)
}
```

The last line inside that lambda body, that's the line that matters, and it has to be an expression (`Int` in this case), because it is what this lambda returns.

So, can the last line be `b = b + 1`? No, because it is not an expression an therefore cannot be returned as such.

Even if you would use `Any` or `Unit` as return type doesn't change the fact that `b = b + 1` is neither of those.

> What I had to do to get around this was do this: blah2 { k = k + 1;
>   Unit }, otherwise my lambda didn't work

Yes, because Unit is a valid expression and `blah2 { k = k + 1; Unit }` is the same as

```
blah2 { 
   k = k + 1 
   Unit // again, last line matters
}
```